# Return a seperate randomized list?

Tags: java, list, collections

I'm wondering if there is a built-in method to return a new randomized list, but all the answers I found is using `Collections.shuffle(list)` that shuffles the original list.

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
// ...

Collections.shuffle(list); // Shuffles the original list
```

Is there some method that returns a new randomized list, instead of the modifying the original list?

Comment: Just make a copy yourself and pass that to shuffle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new List and shuffle it.

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> newList = new LinkedList<>(list);
Collections.shuffle(newList);
```